# QML: Is there Grid Layout's signal "onChildren's initial resizing ended"

Tags: qt, qml, grid-layout

In Qml GridLayout with Repeater in it firstly creates items with zero x,y coordinates, width and height. After it emits Component.onComleted signal. And then moves items to correct coordinates, then resizes them.

```
GridLayout {
    id: inputPanel

    property var tableModel

    rowSpacing: 0
    columnSpacing: 0

    Repeater {
        model: inputPanel.tableModel
        delegate: KeyButton {    
            displayedText: model.display

            Layout.minimumHeight: tableModel.elementSize.height
            Layout.minimumWidth: tableModel.elementSize.width
            Layout.maximumHeight: tableModel.elementSize.height
            Layout.maximumWidth: tableModel.elementSize.width

            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter

            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

**Keybutton.qml**

```
Item {
    id: keyButton

    anchors.margins: 2.5
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Is there any way to catch a moment, when KeyButtons already will have correct x, y, width, height. (KeyButton.onXChanged is not best way, because it emits, when Grid Layout's size changes too)

Comment: Simple curiosity, why do you want it?

Comment: I want to know, that initialization process fully ended. I should familiarise KeyButtons with C part. And i want to know, when KeyButton ->width request starts to give actual results

Comment: Why do not you use the onWidthChanged signal and verify that it is the correct size for the first time?

Comment: It a solution. But it helps really only for first time, because it emits every time, when Width property changes. But i want to call linked slot only once. Or i should save Widths QVector and refresh it every time, when onWidthChanged called it looks not pretty.

Comment: simple, use a flag that is true at the beginning and then change it to false the first that the change arises.